# How to download file given raw data?

Tags: javascript, json, browser, download, binaryfiles

I have a web service call that returns {"data": BINARYDATA}. How can I pop up a dialog to download the file based on only those binary data? It could be a file of any type. I'm probably looking for a Javascript function, or maybe a browser-specific function? Thanks.

**EDIT:** I am checking to see how the data are encoded. Will update soon with that (important) information.

**EDIT 2:** I investigated [Using HTML5/Javascript to generate and save a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897619/using-html5-javascript-to-generate-and-save-a-file/4551467#4551467) . Thank you for the referral.
**My main problem with the dataURI method is that my files are larger than 256kB**

Comment: How are the binary data encoded? (If they're just thrown unencoded and undelimited into a JSON document, then good luck with that!)

Comment: Where are you contacting the web service from? Are you using ASP.NET...Ruby on Rails...PHP...ASP?

Comment: Are you willing to use bleeding-edge HTML5 features? They are not available in all browsers (yet).

Comment: See [Using HTML5/Javascript to generate and save a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897619/using-html5-javascript-to-generate-and-save-a-file).

Answer (score 1):

Resolved:

The answer is that this is not a good client-side task (particularly when dealing with large files). It's much better to change the server-side code to return the appropriate HTTP response (with headers) instead of JSON.

Thanks everyone for your help in the comments.